# Are there security issues with using ajax to send user objects to server?

Tags: ajax, security

I have an application and I want users to have the ability to create a user instantly without even having the page to reload (So that if they are in the middle of something they dont have to stop). I have used ajax for similar things in the past however I am a bit scared using it for something like users with passwords (I am using hash salt and pepper but still, im a bit paranoid). Are there any security issues with that?

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX is not a problem.

Using hash, salt, and pepper is fine, but do you check user's email address for receipt? You can send a six-digit number to the email address entered by the user, and ask the user to enter that number on the input form to confirm that the user can use the email address.